# Does Visual Studio 2008 have a "method view"

Tags: visual-studio

I'm not sure how to describe this except with reference to the Eclipse IDE.  Using the eclipse package explorer when you click the "+" sign next to a class, it expands to show all the methods in alphabetical order.  Using visual studio, the default solution explorer appears to only display the class names.  Is there some way to achieve Eclipse-like functionality with visual studio 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah they call it [Class View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy6s2t6h%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

VS 2008 does show method names for every class, though they do not branch out from the class name. Methods and members appear in a bottom pane in the Class View.